# Should I exclude countries with poor page speed to prevent Google PageSpeed Insights using aggregate data?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, ranking, search, page-speed

Google has mentioned they use the aggregate data to rank a site. I have poor scores and flagged in search console. When viewing google analytics it shows countries like India increasing the overall score.

If my target audience is USA should I exclude traffic from countries who increase score?Especially if my goal is to increase organic search traffic?

https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-advises-against-using-nofollow-links-when-migrating-sites/372155/#close

[image: india traffic increases page load time]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "exclude traffic"? Do you mean some Google setting or directive, or blocking users from visiting your site?

Comment: You might trying adding a CDN into the mix so that your content is cached and delivered from server nodes that are closer to _all_ geographical locations. That might help to speed up your USA and India page loads without having to exclude any audiences. Many CDN's offer a free tier level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, the best solution is to work on your overall load-speed instead of targeting locations to exclude. 5-8 seconds is a really slow load time but also remember that the "score" you are talking about is one ranking factor among hundreds of factors, factors like CTR and Session Duration have a much higher weight on your ranking than global page speed.

If optimizing still doesn't get the results you need there is a more advanced solution you could implement which is to use JavaScript techniques to have pages render differently based on location, device, IP address etc... So for example you could use your analytics data to decide which devices or locations might be having a hard time and us JS to render a stripped down versions of the website to those specific people.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should fix your page speeds. Even `4.9` seconds to the USA is slow - you should be aiming for less then `2` seconds.  Maybe start by looking at Google Lighthouse (built into Chrome) for what's making it slow and improve that.

Google is not looking at the time it takes for others to load and render your pages, they are looking at the time it takes for their servers to.

Comment: Thanks davidgo for your comment and help.